# Using multiple fragment identifiers in a URL

Tags: javascript, hash, jquery-tools

I was wondering whether I can use multiple fragment identifiers in a url, sort of like this:
`http://example.com/videos/index.html#videos#video_2`

I'm using jQuery Tools tabbing system on my index.html page, with the history plugin. This page's "Videos" tab has a flash video player and list of videos on it. Clicking on a video thumbnail loads the file into the player.

I would like a visitor to be able to bookmark not just the #videos tab, but also a specific video.

Am I going about it totally wrong to think having two fragment identifiers in the URL would be the way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you simply want the bookmark to jump to a specific place on the page?  Or do you actually want to load the correct video when they open the link?

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that a double anchor link is impossible!

You could put a pointer to the correct tab and video in the query string of the url (e.g. mysite.com/videos/index.html?tab=video&video=2) and then parse this in JavaScript.  This can then be bookmarked.

However couldn't you stick with the original model (using a single # anchor link) and then simply use JavaScript to find which tab that  tag is in, and therefore show the correct tab?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use multiple hashtags in an URL. The identifier after the hash characters leads to a bookmark anchor on the page, and you can only go to one anchor, you can't go to two anchors at the same time.

If you are bookmarking a video, the natural thing would be that the URL leads to the video, and if you need to show a specific tab in the page you should have code that recognises the video anchor and shows the correct tab.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression to parse URL fragment after `#` is like this:

```
(#(.*))?
```

It means that every character could be passed. So,
choose one of these two approaches:

1. convert all hashes after the first one to '%23'. also you need to do this ( converting to %HEX eq.) for all non acceptable or reserved characters.
   **ex: http://domain.com/app#first%23second**
2. Use multiple hashes and deal it in app!
   the first is easy but may not be implementable in your specific app.

see [this doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) to ensure about valid characters after `#`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use a link like this:

```
index.html#video_2
```

Then parse the hash to get the ID of the video:

```
if (location.hash.indexOf("#video_" === 0)) {
    var index = location.hash.indexOf('_')
    var id = location.hash.substring(index + 1)
    // use jQuery to click the 'videos' tab
    // load the video with id
}
```

You could also listen to the ["hashchange"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange#The_hashchange_event) event, just in case someone copy/pastes a URL for a specific video while already on your web page (e.g. with a different hash):

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",function(event){
    // check hash for video with ID
});
```